# Unity Double Click event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, double-click

I am new here and I'm beginning my adventure with UNITY. I have problem with double click event. I'd like to buying or selling something in my shop. When I assign a button on unity (`public Button button;`) earlier it works. But when i try this change to button on Start and Update methods:

```
    void Start () {
    button = GameObject.Find(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name).GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(ButtonListner);
}
void Update()
{
    button = GameObject.Find(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name).GetComponent<Button>();
}
private void ButtonListner()
{
    counter++;
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        StartCoroutine("doubleClickEvent");
    }
}

IEnumerator doubleClickEvent()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clickTimer);
    if (counter > 1)
    {...}
```

the method doubleClickEvent() doesnt work unfortunately...
What shall I do? Regards ;)

Comment: Why exactly it is not working? Is it not being called or is it not doing the expected?

Comment: The problem is that in the `Update` method you are reassigning the button but not adding a click event handler to it using `AddListener`.  If you changing the button I'd imagine you would need to remove the listener on the button, assign the new button, and then add the listener to the new button.

Comment: Chris Thank you it help me. But I have now different. When i start that I have all the time on red nullRefferenceExeption before I choose an item in shop. This can be solved somehow?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed was: `button = GameObject.Find(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name).GetComponent<Button>();`

The `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` property can be `null` at anytime especially in the first frame which means that using it in the `Start` function is not a good idea. Find the `Button` GameObject then get the `Button` component from it:

```
Button button;

void Start()
{
    button = GameObject.Find("YourButtonName").GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(ButtonListner);
}
```

Replace `"YourButtonName"` with the name of your `Button` GameObject.

---

You don't even need to do most of the stuff you did. You can get double click or click count with [`PointerEventData.clickCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-clickCount.html) from the [`OnPointerClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.OnPointerClick.html) function. You must implement the [`IPointerClickHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface for this to work.

Simply attach to the `Button` GameObject:

```
public class ClickCountDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        int clickCount = eventData.clickCount;

        if (clickCount == 1)
            OnSingleClick();
        else if (clickCount == 2)
            OnDoubleClick();
        else if (clickCount > 2)
            OnMultiClick();
    }

    void OnSingleClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Single Clicked");
    }

    void OnDoubleClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Double Clicked");
    }

    void OnMultiClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("MultiClick Clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: *`The EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject property can be null at anytime`* Not to mention that presumably, `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` is the object returned by the subsequent `GameObject.Find(...)`...

Comment: Its working for desktop, but not for mobile. I want Double Tap

Answer (score 1):

You can detect double click without a coroutine like the following:

```
// Choose the time you want between clicks to consider it a double click
float doubleClickTime = .2f, lastClickTime;    

void Update()
{
    // Checking left mouse button click, you could choose the input you want here
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        float timeSinceLastClick = Time.time - lastClickTime;

        if (timeSinceLastClick <= doubleClickTime)
            Debug.Log("Double click");
        else
            Debug.Log("Normal click");

        lastClickTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```